# Swift 3: func largestNumber

Tags: swift, swift3

I do not have good skills at development so don't laugh at me. But now I make some tests to improve my skills at coding and I have some question. At Apple dev guide I can't find an answer.

So Swift 3 title "Given an integer n, return the largest number that contains exactly n digits"

All I know is it is

```
func largestNumber(n: Int) -> Int {
```

Example:
For n = 2, the output should be
largestNumber(n) = 99

Tell me please how to code it.

Comment: This is not the proper site to ask such basic questions. You need to spend time with lots of tutorials and read [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) book. Update your question after you at least try something.

Comment: Thx, i see that book befor. I look at Guide Functions but dont see "largestNumber". I can find only function where need to choose from array.

Comment: Of course you are not going to `largestNumber`. You have to write it yourself. Use the book to learn the Swift language. Then you have to think about how you find the largest number and then you write that idea into code.

Comment: I understand what result i need in output, but i noob in this area so try some web tests and guides to learn.

Comment: @D1zg check out https://www.codecademy.com/ , pick any languge and just learn the fundamentals. Good luck

Comment: @DanBeaulieu i use codefights.com and pick swift becouse i'm game designer and want to learn how to code (simply) at iOS.

Comment: @D1zg what you'll come to learn is that many programming languages are similiar. Many lanugages offer many of the same features. Once you learn one, you'll gain an intuition of another. So, I offered codeacademy.com as a solution to learn the core fundamentals of programming more rapidly.... then you can apply them to Swift. Just a thought.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu thx, i will tru it.

Answer (score 0):

All the comments at the time of writing on your question have taken the view that you are asking a *coding* question - i.e. how do I write this in Swift - rather than an *algorithm* question - i.e. what is the mathematical/algorithmic solution to this problem?

As others have pointed out SO is not for getting things written for you - code or algorithms - but giving you some pointers to explore is another matter. So tackling the second problem, here are some things to explore:

- If you don't know what a *logarithm* is find out.
- Consider that log10(10) = 1, log10(100) = 2, etc. there is a pattern here. Can you relate those logarithm values to the solution to your problem in some way?
- Having done that what might the log10 of the maximum `Int` value tell you?
- Could you use what you've determined so far to test the parameter `n` of your `largestNumber` function to make sure you can produce a valid answer (i.e. one which is less than or equal to the maximum `Int` value)?
- You state that `largestNumber(2) = 99`, write 99 as a formula containing a power of 10? How about 999? Spot a pattern?

Once you've an algorithm you can then code it in Swift (or Objective-C, Basic, Java, FORTRAN, Ada, Jovial, Go, Haskell, etc., etc., etc...)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you

```
func largestNumber(digits: Int) -> Int{
    var numStr = "0"  

    for i in 0..<digits {
        //since the biggest digit in the decimal system is 9 we append that to our String
        numStr += "9"
    }

    //convert String to Int 
    return Int(numStr) ?? 0
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the answer:

```
    function largestNumber(n) {
var sum="";
   for (i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
       sum+="9";
console.log(sum);
   }
    return parseInt(sum);
}
```